# Target text with jQuery without attributes

Tags: jquery, forms, text, label

I need to target a plain text within a form via jQuery, so that I can wrap a label around it. The form itself is created by an external plugin which I can't edit. As the id's, values and names of the inputs might be changed by the plugin, I can't take these as selectors. That's what makes it difficult for me.

Here is an example code:

```
<form method="post" action="#" name="process213">
    <input id="page_action327" type="hidden" value="confirmation" name="page_action">
    <input id="special108" type="hidden" value="coupon" name="special">
    Text
    <input id="coupon_code" type="text" maxlength="20" name="coupon_code">
    <input type="submit" value="Einlösen" title="Einlösen">
</form>
```

I need to target "Text". Does anyone have an idea how to achieve that without using the above mentioned attributes? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
$('form[name=process213]').contents().filter(function(){
    return this.nodeType === 3 // Node.TEXT_NODE
}).wrap('<label />');
```

**Update**:

and then to delete empty labels you can do just:

```
$( 'form[name=process213] label:empty' ).remove();
```

Comment: Well that's close. It wraps the label around the text, but unfortunately it also creates empty labels before and after each input..

Comment: Actually I just found another way, based on your suggestion that works for me: $('form[name=process213]').contents().filter(function(index){
                return index === 4 
            }).wrap('<label />'); I just don't really get why 4 is the correct index.

Comment: @Sebsemillia I think this is because of text indention, new lines, etc that can be interpreted as text nodes

Comment: Ah ok, that is why your method does add the empty labels at these points as well.. :) Thank you very much, I learned something new today! :)